# How to imitate the following template in a TextBlock?

Tags: c#, xaml, styles, microsoft-metro, textblock

I was looking two metro applications where they're using a particular TextBlock style similar like a dialog.

The following snapshot was taken from TweetPro. Watch the textBlock style where says:

> Te gustaria programar..?

This one is taken from Messaging applications, and watch the purple dialogs.

[image][image]

I'd like to implement this textblock style to my application, but I really have no much experience customizing controls. So, I'd need some of help to implement this textBlock dialog style! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="200" Height="50">
        <Path Data="M 17 0 L 0 0 17 10 Z" StrokeThickness="48" Fill="Red" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
        <Border Background="Red" Padding="5" Width="200" Height="50" >
            <TextBox  BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Text="Hello" Foreground="White" />
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
```